# should AC ground (earth) and DC ground be connected?

Tags: power, ac, dc, ground

I have a power supply (AC --> DC) powering an microcontroller and DC electric motors. I also have the same AC powering a speed controller, which feeds to an AC motor.

Should I be connecting the ground from the DC power supply, to the earth ground on the AC?

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the power supply, but probably not.

Comment: What do you think you would achieve in doing so?

Comment: Are you sure the AC/DC power supply doesn't already reference the DC output return to protective earth? Is it a wall-wart or one with a PE connection? (You didn't specify...)

Comment: You can connect to chassis ground from DC, but usually you keep the chassis between AC gnd and DC gnd. If you have no chassis ground then no, keep them unconnected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My opinion only.

Unless there is a regulatory requirement for your circuit ground to be connected to the AC power ground, I would *NOT* connect them together.  The main reason to keep your circuit floating is to avoid possible ground loops that might occur if you connect your micro controller to another piece of equipment (computer, etc).

There are specific classes of product where there is regulatory requirement that the circuit ground must be connected to AC ground.  But if your product is not one of those, I normally wouldn't do it.